# Sharepoint designer workflow: error on multiple choice field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that sends an email to multiple users when a choice is made.It's a multi-choice field, meaning user's can select more than one. I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed steps of your workflow? Also, are you getting an error when you try to read from a multi-choice field in Designer?

Comment: Change the "InquiredSite" column "Return field us" to other options. Try to use log message in your WF, only then we can get the exact line we stuck.

Comment: @LittSpector I have a multi-choice field that user's can select from. Each selection has to send email to different users. For e.g. if I select site A,B and D - it sends emails to three different email addresses. I've tried using the if value contains condition.. however it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the Call Http Web service to get multiple choices column value?

If that’s the case, it’s default behavior that the output in the “Get an Item from dictionary” is String, but the result of multiple choice actual returned is not String. Then there are conflict.

As a workaround, check the article below to use Call HTTP Service to retrieve choice column values:

[SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflows Using Call HTTP Service to retrieve choice column values](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/elizabethv/2015/03/16/sharepoint-2013-designer-workflows-using-call-http-service-to-retrieve-choice-column-values/)